# When To Use "Static" For Persistence

Tags: c++

I understand that static can provide persistence to things in c++, but I was confused about when it is necessary.

For instance, if I had a function:

```
const int get5(){
  int x = 5;
  return x;
}
```

And I printed out the return, 5 would naturally appear. But, if I try the same with arrays:

```
const int* getArray() {
    int arr[5];
    arr[0] = 5;
    arr[1] = 6;
    arr[2] = 7;
    arr[3] = 8;
    arr[4] = 9;
    return arr;
}
```

And I iterate through each element of the array, I just get giberish:

```
const int* ptr = getArray();
for (int index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
    cout << ptr[index] << endl;
}
```

Results:

```
5
19920968
257848734
258124688
258124688
```

However, if I preface arr with the static modifier, giving it persistence, it works:

```
5
6
7
8
9
```

My question is, why do I need to declare the array as static for its values to be persistent, but in other types, it is not necessary? Thanks!

Comment: Note that immediately after `return arr;`, your array is no longer in scope. What you're seeing is the result of undefined behavior. If you define `arr` to be static, it won't get deallocated until the end of the program.

Comment: ***I iterate through each element of the array, I just get giberish*** It's undefined behavior to return a pointer to a local variable.

Comment: In the first example your function returns a copy of `x`. In the second example, your function returns a pointer to `arr` which was created on the stack just for the duration of your function, but which has sadly gone when you come to print it. Either make `arr` static, which means it hangs around between function calls, or create it on the heap using `new`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is, why do I need to declare the array as `static` for its values to be persistent, but in other types, it is not necessary?

It is because with arrays, a pointer to the array's data is being returned, whereas with other types it is a copy of the data.

---

In the following function:

```
const int* getArray() {
    int arr[5];
    ...
    return arr;
}
```

`arr` in the expression in the last statement decays into a pointer to the first element of the array. The function `getArray()` is returning this pointer  (and **not** a copy of the array) which points to data with *automatic storage duration*. Therefore after the function returns, that data should be no longer accessed.

However, if you declare the array `arr` as `static`, even though you are still returning a pointer to the first element of the array, this data does persist after the function returns.

Comment: Thanks for going into the static part as well! Great answer.

Answer (score 5):

The difference is that in the first example you're returning a *copy*, in the second you're returning a *pointer*. When you return a copy it doesn't matter if the original value is destroyed. But when you return a pointer, you must ensure that the lifetime of the pointed-to object goes beyond the end of the function or you will get undefined behavior.

Comment: ͏+͏1͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏ Being able to answer this so clearly is a talent.

Comment: @Bathsheba thank you very much for the compliment.  It comes from lots of practice. It was all part of Jeff Atwood's master plan: https://blog.codinghorror.com/how-to-write-without-writing/

Comment: Gotcha. that makes perfect sense! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

arr is created in the local scope, meaning it is discarded once the function returns. The memory it occupied (in this case, it most likely resides in registers) is then used by other processes (or by the next instructions in your program if registers are used), which is why you see strange values.

Comment: Interesting! Thanks for expanding into how those values arose!